# How to get data from html in android

Tags: android

I have get html data from webpage. But i want to get only data excluding html tags.

I have tried this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlText.getText().toString());
// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InutStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
{
   textView.append(line);
   sb.append(line+"\n");
}
```

This giving me whole html data. Tell me now i can get data only.

Comment: "This giving me whole html data. Tell me now i can get data only." ? Means you want only data without html tags? right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Html.fromHtml(source)`? or use any **Java HTML parser** (If they work on android) for this.

Here `source` is your html formatted whole data.

EDIT:

```
 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
String source = sb.toString();
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(source));
```

Look at this example [Android Parsing HTML Content Containing Links](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-parsing-html-content-containing-links).